# Is it possible to attach a name to a runtime class in C++?

Tags: c++, typeid

I have an hierarchy of classes, the base class having a function to print the class name:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
  virtual void print_name() { cout << typeid(*this).name() << endl; };
};

class derived1 : public base { };

class derived2 : public base { };

int main ()
{
  base Base;
  Base.print_name();

  derived1 Derived1;
  Derived1.print_name();

  derived2 Derived2;
  Derived2.print_name();
}
```

The output of the above is

```
class base
class derived1
class derived2
```

which is, in fact, platform dependent.

Is there a more or less standard way to "attach" some unique name to each class, so it could be used in `printname()` making the output the same for all platforms (and independent of any changes made to real class names)?

Comment: just a silly question: in how much is this platform dependent?

Comment: Very much. For example, gcc does not include the word "class" to the result (and may add something more). The standard says: "The names, encoding rule, and collating sequence for types are all unspecified and may differ between programs".

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
class base {
  public:
    virtual char const *name() const { return "base"; }
};

class derived1 : public base {
  public:
    virtual char const *name() const { return "derived1"; }
};
```

However, if you do not override `name` in a class, its name will be that of its superclass. That may be a bug or a feature, depending on your use case. If it's a bug, then you can add some runtime checks to make sure the method is overridden:

```
virtual char const *name() const {
    if (typeid(*this) != typeid(base))
        throw std::logic_error("name() not overridden");
    return "base";
}
```

But you'll have to repeat this check in every implementation of `name` that must be overridden.

Comment: Thank you. But specifics of my case is that I am not allowed to change headers of any of derived classes, which is needed if I introduce a new function to return the name. However, I am free to do anything with the base class (or introduce any new classes, of course). What can I do, then?

Comment: @G-s: very little, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You can effectively use `type_info` for this.

`type_info` supports a `before` method conforming to a Weak Order, which allows its use in a `std::map` (for example) as long as a user-supplied predicate is provided.

```
struct TypeInfoLess {
     bool operator()(std::type_info const* lhs, std::type_info const* rhs) const {
         return lhs->before(rhs);
     }
};

struct AdditionalTypeInfo {
    std::string name;
};

typedef std::map<std::type_info const*, AdditionalTypeInfo, TypeInfoLess> TypeInfoMap;
```

Then, you can just add/search types:

```
template <typename T>
void add(TypeInfoMap& map, T const& t, AdditionalTypeInfo const& ati) {
    map[&typeid(t)] = ati;
}

template <typename T>
AdditionalTypeInfo const* find(TypeInfoMap const& map, T const& t) {
    TypeInfoMap::const_iterator it = map.find(&typeid(t));
    if (it == map.end()) { return 0; }
    return &it->second;
}

int main() {
    TypeInfoMap timap;

    add(timap, timap, { "TypeInfoMap" });

    if (AdditionalTypeInfo const* const ati = find(timap, timap)) {
        std::cout << ati->name << "\n";
    }
}
```

*Note: it is then your responsability to add to the map every type that you might want.*

Comment: Seems interesting. This name-matching stuff could be united into a special singleton class. But what if I would like to define the classes' names in their implementation sections, not in some special place of code? It could look like a macros of the form SETNAME(TypeInfoMap,"TypeInfoMap") that should add the class to the list. And if there is no macros in class definition, some default name should be returned for it. Can it be done?

Comment: @G-s: well a Singleton here is overkill, a simple global is sufficient if you really want to go down that road; but I would advise against it. The registration however cannot really be done "in the class", you can call a method as par of initializing a global variable (or local static) to emulate those registry mechanisms but you expose yourself to the static initialization order fiasco; so it may become painful.

Comment: It seems that following another answer in this topic, simple returning a string by an overloaded function, gives a way to define names in interface sections of classes. Does it have any disadvantages compared to your way if I am allowed to modify derived classes the way I want to? At least it doesnt't need registrating classes in some special place which seems to be inconvenient.

Comment: @G-s: well, of course using inheritance is much lighter and way less cumbersome. If you can do so, go ahead! The premise of this answer was your remark that you could not edit the classes themselves.

Comment: In fact, all my derived classes' interfaces already have a macro defined in the base class (which, as I said before, can be modified in any manner). So I can make GetName() a member of each class and define names in classes' implementations using another macro (SETNAME I mentioned before). And it works well, but only if I use this SETNAME macro for every class, whereas I would prefer to omit it if a class doesn't need a specific name becase there are much more such classes. I can't omit it because I get unresolved symbol (since the function is in interface). What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template functions (or traits classes) to get names:

```
template<typename T> const char * ClassName(T const * objPtr);

template<> const char * ClassName<derived1>(derived1 const *objPtr) { return "derived1"; }
template<> const char * ClassName<derived2>(derived2 const *objPtr) { return "derived2"; }
```

(Here the function parameter is used for template parameter matching only).
And in calling code you can cast your pointer to specific class and use ClassName

```
derived1 * pDerived = static_cast<derived1*>(pPointer);
cout << ClassName(pDerived);
```

However this is all compile-time, and you will need some mechanism (like GUIDs) to identify a class at runtime  (to cast it to the right pointer type). If your classes have none and you can't modify them, than I can't help you;( But you can use traits technique to localize your platform-dependent type selection code.

Comment: It has some issues with dynamic values: how do you identify the real type of `pPointer` ?

Comment: Sure, you have to "know" the exact type of your pPointer somehow. Say, if author's classes have some enumeration, he could use it to deduce the correct type (and templates could help with this).